# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (name, phone) VALUES ('Антон', '46363466356')' at line 1

**Order**

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Order
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name): void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $phone
     */
    public function setPhone($phone): void
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;
    }
}
```

И вот собственно сам контролер

```
        $order = new Order();
        $form = $this->createForm(OrderType::class, $order);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $order->setName($form->get('name')->getData());
            $order->setPhone($form->get('phone')->getData());
            $em->persist($order);
            $em->flush();
        }
```

OrderType:

```
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Order;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class OrderType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Контактное лицо', 'label' => null],
            ])
            ->add('phone', null, ['attr' => ['placeholder' => '+7 (___) ___-__-__']]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Order::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Order` это зарезервированное слово в mysql (используется в `ORDER BY field`). Поэтому таблицу надо назвать по другому и указать это в аннотации:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="my_orders",
 * )
 */
```

Также: нет смысла перекладывать в `$order` то, что в нем **уже есть**: после сабмита формы все её данные заполняют объект `$order`, поэтому если вывести объект `$order` после сабмита - то ты увидишь, что его поля уже заполнены:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    // print_r($order);
    $em->persist($order);
    $em->flush();
}
```